# ul li affecting height

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, html-lists

so i'm really stuck with this one for a whole day, i have was trying to use any plugins, that will affect height of footer.

```
<!-- FAQ -->
            <section class="faq-container">
                <div class="faq-width">
                    <div class="faq-head">Часто задаваемые вопросы</div>
                    <ul class="faq-list">
                        <li>1.<a href"#" id="hide">В каких типах помещений можно устанавливать натяжной потолок?</a>
                            <li class="show">Устанавливать потолки можно в любых помещениях, они абсолютно безопасны. Запрещается установка в помещениях с повышенной температурой (парилки, горячие цеха и т.д.), а так же в неотапливаемых помещениях, где температура опускается ниже 0. </li>
                        </li>
                        <li>2.<span>На какой стадии ремонта лучше устанавливать натяжной потолок?</span></li>
                        <li>3.<span>На какую высоту опустятся потолки при установке?</span></li>
                        <li>4.<span>Как долго служат натяжные потолки?</span></li>
                        <li>5.<span>Очень ли заметен шов на пленке ПВХ?</span></li>
                        <li>6.<span>Какой уход необходим потолкам?</span></li>
                        <li>7.<span>Пахнут ли натяжные потолки?</span></li>
                        <li>8.<span>Вредят ли натяжному потолку протечки воды сверху?</span></li>
                        <li>9.<span>Каким способом потолочные люстры подвешивают к натяжному потолку?</span></li>
                        <li>10.<span>Нужно ли выносить всю мебель из комнаты при установке натяжного потолка?</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>

            <!-- FOOTER -->
            <footer role="contentinfo">
                <div class="contact-container">
                    <div class="contact-head">
                        <span class="contact-us"> Свяжитесь с нами! </span>
                    </div>
                    <form action="#" method="POST" class="contact-middle">
                        <input type="text" name="fullname" class="name-email" placeholder="Имя" tabindex="1" id="name" />
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="name-email" id="email" placeholder="Email" tabindex="2" />
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="msg" placeholder="Сообщение должно быть больше 15 букв" class="name-email" id="message" tabindex="3"></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" id="btn-send" value="Отправить">Отправить</button>
                        <span class="required-note">Все поля обязательны</span>
                    </form>
                    <div class="contact-end">
                        <span class="copyright">&copy; IRPEX, 2008-2014<a href="mailto:griesti@irpex.lv"> griesti@irpex.lv </a></span>
                        <a href="http://jetcode.lv" class="jetcode-logo">jetcode.lv</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
```

So basically what i'm trying to achive, when you click on any li question in (faq-list) it should dropdown answer and also affect height of whole footer, so it's like footer is "auto sliding" depending on faq answers, i was trying to write if and else statements, but nothing worked for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/5CdKr/

Comment: Please provide your JS/CSS as well and a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com) example.

Comment: With a fiddle it would help a lot. Still, if you keep a fix height on your footer (css) it's normal that the size doesn't change when you add content to it.

Comment: okey, one moment :) http://jsfiddle.net/5CdKr/

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand your question right. If you want to let the footer slide together with the li element you should change overflow of the list item from hidden to auto.

```
.nav-list
{
  Overflow:auto;
}
```